# Calling for a channel with discord.utils.get returns "None"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So basically what I want to do is create a channel with the name Ticket-(name and tag of the person) and then call it for a ctx.author.send so the person can go into the channel from their DMs, this is the code:

```
async def _1(ctx):

    guild = client.get_guild(742566911778357330)
    supportroom = ('bot-commands')
    name = 'Tickets'
    rolename = 'Staff'
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=744151796439711825)
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=rolename)
    overwrites = {
guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages= False),
    guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
 ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
 role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }

    if str(ctx.channel) in supportroom:
        {
        }
    else:
        await guild.create_text_channel('Ticket %s' % ctx.author, overwrites=overwrites, category=category)
        await ctx.author.send('**Your ticket has been created.**')
```

the problem is from this line forward

```
        print(ctx.message.author)
        nameChannelTicket = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, guild__name=guild, name=(('Ticket-%s') % (ctx.author)))
        print(nameChannelTicket)
        await ctx.author.send('Your ticket is %s' % nameChannelTicket)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been working on it for more than 4 hours :)

https://prnt.sc/u02ezq
That is what gets sent from the discord perspective ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than going through all of the trouble of trying to find the channel. Why don't we define it?

```
channel = await guild.create_text_channel('Ticket %s' % ctx.author, overwrites = overwrites, category = category)
```

Now that we have defined it, we can call it!

```
await ctx.author.send('Your ticket is %s' % channel.name)
```

Now you can totally get rid of defining nameChannelTicket.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @StarbuckBarista! Very helpful, however when I wanted to click on the name to go directly to the channel it wouldn't let me as it just displays as a normal text, instead what I did was this:

```
        nameChannelTicket = await guild.create_text_channel('Ticket %s' % ctx.author, overwrites=overwrites, category=category)
        await ctx.author.send('**Your ticket has been created.**')
        print(ctx.message.author)
        print(nameChannelTicket)
        await ctx.author.send('Your ticket is <#%s>' % nameChannelTicket.id )
```

This way it would get the channel id and call it later, which allowed me to get inside the channel by one click, without having to call the guild, again very helpful your answer @StarbuckBarista! Very appreciated.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it all figured out!

Answer (score 0):

try first defining the guild, then using `get` for finding the channel with given name.

```
    print(ctx.message.author)
    guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, id = put_id_here)
    nameChannelTicket = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=(f'Ticket-{ctx.author}'))
    print(nameChannelTicket)
    await ctx.author.send('Your ticket is {0}'.format(nameChannelTicket))
```